# JavaScript - Fetching Associated Values of (this) Parameter in an onclick Function

Tags: javascript, html, onclick, parameter-passing, this

I am passing on (this) parameter to a function thru onclick(). Within the function when I try to fetch "name" attribute of the calling object of a Table Data Cell it fails. Here is the code.

```
<button name="abcd" onclick="foo(this)">
  Button
</button>

<table>
<tr>
  <td name="XYZ" onclick="foo(this)">Click Me Also</td>
</tr>
</table>

<script type="text/javascript">
var foo = function(xparam)
{
    // This one works for both
    alert(xparam.innerHTML);

    // This one doesn't work for Table Cell (though works for Button)
    alert(xparam.name);
};
</script>
```

Here is the JSFiddle http://jsfiddle.net/8cvBM/312/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`name` may not be an property for all the elements (as per [doc](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/HTML/Element/table) `table` doesn't have name property), so try `getAttribute`

```
alert(xparam.getAttribute("name"));
```